# How to interact with process in haskell

Tags: haskell, process

I compiled the following program

```hs
-- Alice.hs
main = do
  putStrLn "Hello"
  l <- getLine
  putStrLn $ "you said " ++ l
```

I want to communicate with Alice in another program: Bob.hs. My failed attempt is:

```hs
-- Bob.hs
import System.IO (hGetLine, hPutStrLn)
import System.Process (runInteractiveProcess)
main = do
  (hin, hout, herr, ph) <- runInteractiveProcess "./Alice" [] Nothing Nothing
  hello <- hGetLine hout
  putStrLn hello
  hPutStrLn hin "something"
  reply <- hGetLine hout
  putStrLn reply
```

Bob gets stuck before Hello is printed.

Comment: What was the problem with the failed attempt?

Comment: @mkrieger1 thanks, added a brief explaination

Comment: I'd try `hFlush stdout` in Alice before `getLine`. My guess is that when two processes interact directly the usual line buffering discipline on stdout is replaced by block buffering.

Comment: @chi. It seems that Alice works fine when running as a terminal user. In the end I want Bob to communicate with other programs as well, regardless of how they are written, as long as they work to some extend. Therefore if there is a solution that only involve changing Bob's code, then I'd rather have that one.

Comment: If my suspicion is correct, the issue is that Alice does not send her output before blocking for input when not connected to a terminal. If that's the case, there is no easy way to solve the issue on Bob's side, AFAICS.

Comment: This is a well known issue in Unix caused by programs buffering output for efficiency when it's not a tty. If the tool is not flushing as you wanted it to, there are per-tool flags like `grep --line-buffered`, per-framework options like `export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`, and even more creative mechanisms like `stdbuf`'s library injection. The best practice is to work *with* the system and trust the tool to work correctly (or make the user configure it appropriately). If you prefer working *against* the system for (rather short sighted) ease of use, you can use `script` or similar to fake a tty.

Comment: @thatotherguy thanks I didn't know this. I'll start by working with the system then

Comment: @chi could you post what you did to my example to get it working? I have not been succesful at it yet

Comment: @chi EDIT: Seems that adding LineBuffering to `stdout` in Alice and `hin` in Bob has made the example work. Is this also what you did?